# How can a free function to a derived class gain access to an include in the header of the base class?

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

I have a base class and a derived class called `App` and `MyApp` respectively. The `App` base class includes reusable code for a user interface such as setup for OpenGL, glfw, ImGui etc while the derived `MyApp` class includes code specific to the user interface such as calls to various functions which plot lines or shapes.

A reduced version of the base class in `App.h`:

```
#include "imgui.h"
#include "implot.h"
#include "imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
//etc

class App
{

public:
    App();
    virtual ~App()
    virtual void Update() = 0; 
    virtual void StartUp() = 0;
}
```

`MyApp.h` contains some additional function declarations:

```
#pragma once
#include "App.h"
#include "line.h"

class Line;

class MyApp : public App, public IObserver
{
private:
    std::vector<Line> lines;
    Graph g; 
public:
    MyApp() = default;
    ~MyApp() = default;
    virtual void StartUp() final;
    virtual void Update() final;
    void OnNotify(Line l);
    void addLine(Line l);

};

void drawNodes(Graph& g);
```

and the implementation is contained in `MyApp.cpp`

```
void MyApp::Update()
{
    // code to draw the user interface
    ImGui::Begin("Minimum Spanning Tree Visualizer", NULL, flags);
    ImPlot::CreateContext();
    ImPlot::BeginPlot("Spanning Tree", ImVec2(window_width * 0.8, window_height * 0.95), 
    drawNodes(g);
    ImPlot::EndPlot();
    ImGui::End();
}

void MyApp::Startup(){
  //some code 
}

void drawNodes(Graph& g) {
    //some code which formats data and passes it to a function to    
    vector<double> xs_vector, ys_vector;
    for (auto&& node : g.getNodes()) {
        xs_vector.push_back(node->getXY().first);
        ys_vector.push_back(node->getXY().second);
    };
    double* xs = &xs_vector[0];
    double* ys = &ys_vector[0];
    ImPlot::PlotScatter("1", &xs, &ys, ImPlotScatterFlags_None);
}
```

When I compile my code I am getting a linker error which says that the function `ImPLot::PlotScatter` in the free function `drawNodes` cannot be found. calls to `ImGui` and `ImPlot` methods from within `Update` which is defined as a method of the `MyApp` class do link to the library, so my question is why does the compiler not link the the call in the free function to the include of `ImPlot` which is included in the header of the base class? How can I get this free function to "see" the include which is in the base class or would it be better to move the definition of this file into a seperate header which contains an include to `ImPlot` again?

Comment: The include **is** seen, otherwise you would get a compile-time error. If you have a link-time error, then the include has been successfully found, but the definition (TU) is not. Maybe it's a missing dynamic lib, or a path misconfiguration. How is the implot library imported to your project ?

Comment: @Fareanor I'm using CMake and Vcpkg to add ImGui and ImPlot to the project. The only place I include it is in `app_design.h`. The calls from within `MyApp::Update` do work properly, so it's just the calls in the free function `drawNodes` that I get a linker error for.

Comment: Yes but you do not call `ImPlot::PlotScatter()` in `MyApp::update()`. This is this specific function for which the definition is not found, hence the undefined reference. If you use CMake, it could maybe help to add your CMakeLists.txt, maybe there are some missing parts (I don't know Vcpkg but it would help to add the data from it as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest signature to your posted code I could find is this:

`IMPLOT_TMP void PlotScatter(const char* label_id, const T* xs, const T* ys, int count, ImPlotScatterFlags flags=0, int offset=0, int stride=sizeof(T));`

(I looked it up [here](https://github.com/epezent/implot/blob/33c5a965f55f80057f197257d1d1cdb06523e963/implot.h#L860))

So it looks like you forgot the parameter `count` after `xs` and `ys`.

Comment: I've updated my post with the actual code I had there. I removed some of it to create a minimal example but that probably added to the confusion. The signature is indeed wrong though, it runs if I pass xs and ys by value and not by reference and also pass a value for int count.